# Jira - allow public to add bugs

Tags: jira

We've just bought a 10 user Jira license - happy as larry.

I'm a reet n00b to Jira, one of our guys is fully versed but away atm. One question I have is:

is it possible to allow the public (our beta users) to submit bugs somehow without using up our user licenses? They just need to be able to submit bugs, viewing status would be great but not essential.

this may be one really obvious thing - i just can't see it?

w://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 options:

1. Create a single user that the public can use and put it on the announcement page. So they can login with it.
2. Set a jira service, to create issue from email, and assign that issue to a user - called it anonymous probably. This is if you are not "happy" to allow anonymous user to login.
3. Set in permission scheme - group anyone, to be able to create an issue. And then set a custom "screen" with a "field config scheme" to set reporter as optional, this will allow anonymous user as reporter.